# Magento unable to send eMail, exeption error

Tags: email, ce-1.9.1.0, smtp, send-mail

I got this error message in my exception file.

```
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in /lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:137
Stack trace:
#0 /lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
#1 /lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#2 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php(241): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue->send(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
#4 /app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(325): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#6 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#9 /cron.php(76): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#10 {main}
2015-01-21T13:00:01+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in /lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:137
```

Is this issue in Magento, or its Server issue?

Comment: Server issue for sure. Try using the default mail() function to test first.

Comment: please check email  server  is enable or not in server

Comment: It looks like you are getting this error as no mail server is configured on the server. To confirm look for postfix or sendmail. If this is a managed host they can install otherwise let me know and i can help you install based on operating system.

Comment: We solved it by setting a selinux var for mail server.

Answer (score 4):

You can check following possibilities.

1) First check that your server is having email server configured or not.

2) If you have moved your Magento code and Database from some server to your localhost or development server.

Then you should check at following location in Magento admin

```
System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail Sending option
```

*`Host`* value should be localhost. (It may contains some IP address which might be configured on actual server from where you take the DB.)

[image: screehshot]

3) If you are getting this exception on your locahost on standalone PC, then you must configure an email server to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved, restarting 'Postfix' service in my server.