# Contact Us form not working

Tags: magento-1.9, email, contact-us, contact-form

I am using Magento 1.9. I had configure the mail setting and my newsletter mail also working properly.

But when I tried "About Us" it show me the below error message

> Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later

i had also go through the code. The `$mail->send();` function generate an exception

> Unable to send mail.

i am not getting the issue.
Please help me to solve same.

Comment: Did you use sendmail function or SMTP to send email?

Comment: I haven't made any changes in core code.I just fount that under app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Email\Template.php  in that send($email, $name = null, array $variables = array())  function

Comment: Try to run these send email commands on remote server first, probably you can find some errors: http://tecadmin.net/ways-to-send-email-from-linux-command-line/#

Comment: @PY Yick Its's working properly...

Comment: Does `var/log/exception.log` add any new exceptions when "Unable to send mail" show up?

Comment: yes. It showing error message as - exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. '

Comment: Try this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53205/magento-unable-to-send-email-exeption-error

Comment: yeah... I did this already ( set host name properly) but it still showing me same error message

Comment: How about setting the hostname? Ref: https://bjarneo.codes/zend_mail_transport_exception-with-message-unable-to-send-mail/

Comment: thank you for your response. but as i said my newsletter mail working properly then also need to update hostname? can you please give me same more details on it.

Comment: Or you can try restart sendmail first

Comment: did it ( restart sendmail ), but showing same error message

Comment: have you configure contact email in admin side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching lot's of thing i found solution for this problem. This issue can solve by disabling mailQueue.

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php
```

Change Line

> if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof
>   Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {

To

> if (!($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof
>   Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue)) {

for more details visit [here](http://www.prashantblog.com/magento-new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1/)

But there may be case that it can affect other mail module